# a problem with Google Apps script authorisation

Tags: google-apps-script

A few days ago I have met a problem with scripts authorization when SpreadsheetApp is called in a script. The message is as follow

Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not yet been verified by Google in order to use Google Sign in.

It happens on one of my accounts, not a private one.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

As @TheMaster pointed out, there is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820) with Scripts being "unauthorizable". You can follow the issue by clicking on the star next to the issue number to give more priority to the report and to receive updates.